# Java Annotation building .class at compile time

Tags: java, spring, annotations, compile-time

in my project i have to implements some annotations specifying a set of data type and the operation i can do on them.

After this i have to annotate some classes of my models package, specifying in that way what type of operation i can to on this class.

Eventually, at compile time, i have to parse the class with annotated field and build a new model representing the class and each operation i can do on its properties.

I was wondering what if the way i listed below could be a correct way to do this:

For example:

```
public @interface MySearchableType1 {         

    enum operations{
         EQUAL,
         NOT_EQUAL,
         LIKE,
         NOT_LIKE,
         IN,
         NOT_IN     
    }        
 }

public @interface MySearchableType2 {

    enum operations{
        EQUAL,
        NOT_EQUAL               
    }        
}

public class MyClass {

    public String name;

    @MySearchableType1
    public String property1;

    @MySearchableType2
    public String property2;
}
```

the final product should be something like this:

```
public class MyModelClass{
     public Map<String, String[]> property1 = new HasMap<String,String[]>();
    property1.put("property1", ["EQUAL", "NOT_EQUAL", "LIKE", "NOT_LIKE", "IN", "NOT_IN"]); 

    public Map<String, String[]> property2 = new HasMap<String,String[]>();
    property2.put("property21", ["EQUAL", "NOT_EQUAL"]);
}
```

What can i use to reach my target? Is it possible to obtain instanced .class file like the one i wrote maybe using spring? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I hade good use of this tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html. Sorry I don't have a answer for you

Comment: “at compile time and by java reflection” is a contradiction. Reflection works *at runtime*.

Comment: Ok i changed the title... so dp you have a more constructive answer? Is there the possibilty to build my custom .class starting from annotation analysis?

Answer (score 2):

https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/

[How to generate code dynamically with annotations at build time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362659/java-dynamically-generate-code-with-annotations-at-build-time)

Could be an answer