# Extend a type using generics

Tags: swift, generics

In Swift, I am trying to create a generic class that can extend another class, while inheriting from it. I am able to do it in C++ as follows, but is there a way to do the same in Swift?

```
class Atom {};

template<typename Base, typename Extension>
class Extend: Base {
    Extension _value;
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

One approach I have been trying to apply is Protocol Oriented Design, but it doesn't seem to be able to take a class and extend it. The best I reached is something like creating the extension manually, and declaring that it does extend `Atom`, but at that point, I would just create another class and add to it the respective property manually.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is by generating the code for the subclass at compile or run time. check these answers of these questions: 
[How to generate code dynamically with annotations at build time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362659/how-to-generate-code-dynamically-with-annotations-at-build-time-in-java), and [Generating, compiling and using Java code at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051884/generating-compiling-and-using-java-code-at-run-time).
You can add a custom generic method to the base class that would be overridden by each subclass (in the generated code) and it may return Object. It would be a working approach, if it's worth the hassle.